# Undefined CSS attribute (top/left)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this code:
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Joc</title>
</head>
<body onload="funcio()">
    <img src="juanca.jpg" class="rey">
    <img src="elefant.gif" id="elefant">
    <button id="boton"> press me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url("hierba.jpg");
}
.rey {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: top 5s linear, left 5s linear;
}
.reyMov{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
}
#elefant{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 700px;
}
#boton{
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left: 45%;
}
```

JS:

```
function funcio(){
        alert("reyMov orig top "+$(".reyMov").css("top"))
        var posicio = $("#elefant").position();
        $(".reyMov").css("top",posicio.top+"px;");
        var posicio2 = $(".reyMov").position();
        alert("reyMov new top "+posicio2.top);
```

};

As you can see, I have defined top and left attributes for the class reyMov on CSS, but when I try to acces it (with alert), the js console returns me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

I also tried to change this attribute and get it again, but does not work.
Any tip for fixing this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't use an element with class `reyMov`in the page then `$(".reyMov")` won't return any element: thus you are chaining the `css()` method to an empty object and the alert statement will throw that error.

I suppose you are mistyping `rey/reyMov` in the javascript code (or the classname in the markup should be `reyMov` instead of `rey`)

Comment: I do this because I'm trying to trigger a css transition. I need to change the top attribute of "reyMov" in function of the position of "elefant". Isn't it the right way to proceed?

Comment: @pau, sorry but to me it's not clear what *I need to change the top attribute of "reyMov" in function of the position of "elefant"* means. A fiddle with some extra explanation would help a lot

Comment: Well, I'm trying to do a mini game. There is an image of an static elefant that will appear randomly in the document. Y also have an image of a king (rey). I want the king follows the elefant. So I use a transition to obtain this. I'm trying to pass the position of the elefant to the reyMov class, and then change the class of rey to reyMov.
Excuse my English, I am not native.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery, $("") is a selector, it selects elements from the DOM. You've not used the .reyMov class anywhere in  your HTML. You're using jQuery to edit your CSS, at least not in your implementation.

I think you'd want to bind to an element, and apply a class using addClass, or then use the css method to change the css already applied.